Add spacing around figure in typst
I'm using typst 0.11.1.
How do you add spacing between figures, and the subsequent text?
If captions become very long, it can be hard to see where it ends, and the surrounding text begins. Example:
#lorem(50)

#figure(block(width: 100%, height: 10em, fill: green), caption: [Shrek green. #lorem(35)])

#lorem(70)


Where is the option to add padding around a figure?

The figure function inherits from the block function. You can therefore set the default block inset for figures using the following show rule:
#show figure: set block(inset: (top: 0.5em, bottom: 2em))

This code adds 0.5em padding above figures, 2em padding below as was asked, and no padding to the sides.

